# Java: BigDecimal erroneously gives divide-by-0 error

Tags: java, math, eulers-number

I'm trying to calculate Euler's number to a high degree of accuracy using BigDecimals but after a while, the numbers get so small that the JVM throws a divide-by-0 error. Any ideas on how to overcome? I find that the try-catch block is always called after exactly 34 iterations of the division, but I don't know why. The formula for Euler's number is an infinite series, so 34 iterations gets it close to the actual value of *e*, but not as accurate as I'd like it. It's not actually dividing by 0, but it's probably too small for the JVM to tell the difference.

```
    BigDecimal ee = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    for (int k = 0; k < 50; k++) {
        int fact = factorial(k);
        try {
            BigDecimal trial = BigDecimal.ONE.divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(fact), 100, RoundingMode.CEILING);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("---- Div-by-0 error; Iterated " + k + " times ----");
            break;
        }
        ee = ee.add(BigDecimal.ONE.divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(fact), 100, RoundingMode.CEILING));
    }
    System.out.println("\n---- Final: \t\te = " + power(ee, x));
}
```

Comment: It's probably because it's actually dividing by zero.  `fact` is going to overflow, and creating a `BigDecimal` after that still won't have the correct value.

Comment: factorial(49) is 6.0828186e+62. That's way way more than the maximum value of an int.

Answer (score 2):

Your factorial calculations are overflowing.  Your `factorial` method must be returning `int` because you've assigned the return value of that method to `int`.

Starting with `13` the overflow occurs.  13! is 6,227,020,800‬, the first factorial value too large to be represented in an `int`.  Overflow represents this value as `1932053504`.  The problem gets worse as additional values become negative, e.g. 17! is calculated as `-288522240`.

Eventually, enough factors of `2` accumulate in the product that all `1` bits get shifted off the end, leaving `0` (starting at 34!).  This is what caused your division by zero error.

But that is just a symptom of overflow that already occurred much earlier.  Use `BigDecimal` for your factorial calculation to avoid overflow and maintain precision.  That `BigDecimal` can be passed directly to `divide` without conversion.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are using correct datatypes to store values.
Use BigInteger as it can store up to 100! value in it.

Int max values: int 4 bytes -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.

Since you are assigning the value higher than the limit, it will loop back to negative and probably resulting into 0 at some point.

Values of factorial:

> 01! = 1 02! = 2 03! = 6 04! = 24 05! = 120 12! = 479001600
>
> Max value of Int -- 2147483647
>
> 13! = 6227020800